# Shadowing controls and customisation

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, shadow, renderer

I'm trying to get a shadow for my button but it does not work and I dunno why. Since I have seen a lot of post asking how to take it off, I do not why but from the start I didnt have shadow for my buttons. If someone could help ... I'm also trying to achieve that for my StackLayouts to render something like that :

[image]

And last question to avoid opening another post : 
How to make the placeholder move on top of entry when being focus on this entry ?

My code for button

I've got a class :

```
public class ButtonComponent : MR.Gestures.Button
    {

    }
```

A custom renderer :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ButtonComponent), typeof(ButtonComponentRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class ButtonComponentRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Elevation = 9;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The button init :

```
// Login button
        _okButton = new ButtonComponent
        {
            Text = "Validate",
            BackgroundColor = Constants.PrimaryColorOrange,
            HeightRequest = 50,
            WidthRequest = 180,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            TextColor = Color.White 
        };
```

Here is my styles.xml, in case :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FFA100</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#FF8000</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FFA500</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>
  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FFA100</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MainTheme.Splash" parent="MainTheme">
    <!--<style name="MainTheme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">-->    
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF8000</item>
    <!--<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>-->
    <!--<item name="colorPrimary">#FFA100</item>-->
  </style>  
</resources>
```

In case someone asks, the MainActivity

```
 [Activity(
        Label = "App", 
        Icon = "@drawable/icon", 
        Theme = "@style/MainTheme.Splash", 
        MainLauncher = true,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
And androidmanifest

`<application android:label="MyApp.Droid" android:largeHeap="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" >`
Android AppCompat v7 25.4.0.2
```

Thank you all.

Comment: Are you sure the that `Control.Elevation = 9;` gets called?

Comment: Yes it is, I put a breakPoint and another properties setter to see if the renderer works and it is called.
if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Elevation = 9;
                Control.SetBackgroundColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.AliceBlue);
            }

Comment: You could refer to : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/android/appcompat/

Comment: I already did ... thank you anyway